# how can i draw a line on BufferedImage?

Tags: java

I am trying to create some kind of Paint program. I created a BufferedImage and an Graphics2D but i cant draw on it. All what I can see is the BufferedImage itself without any changes.

```
public class paintapp implements ActionListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener
{
public static final int WIDTHBUFF=300;
public static final int HEIGHTBUFF=300;
BufferedImage buffimage=new BufferedImage(WIDTHBUFF,HEIGHTBUFF,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_BGR);
JLabel imagelabel=new JLabel(new ImageIcon(buffimage));
int s=3;
Color curr_color=Color.BLACK;
int x,y;
public static final int WIDTH=700;
public static final int HEIGHT=700;



public paintapp()
{
    Graphics2D g2d=buffimage.createGraphics();
    g2d.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTHBUFF,HEIGHTBUFF);
    JFrame frame=new JFrame("Painter");
    frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setVisible(true);
    Panel buttonpanel=new Panel();
    Panel colors=new Panel();
    Panel draw=new Panel();
    draw.add(imagelabel);
    frame.add(draw);
    frame.pack();



}
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    paintapp paint1=new paintapp();
}
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    Graphics2D g2=buffimage.createGraphics();
    g2.setColor(curr_color);
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(s));
    g2.drawLine(x, y, e.getX(), e.getY());
    x=e.getX();
    y=e.getY();

}
@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    x=e.getX();
    y=e.getY();

}
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: first, put more effort in formatting your code ;)

Answer (score 0):

I see you are poking through and you got things in jumbled up order. If you read the guides you will see how things go.

The first main thing is to add a MouseMotionListener to the drawing thing - be that JLabel JPanel whatever.

The second thing is that once you go outside of the constructor the JFrame is lost (unless you do some fancy things) and cant be accessed to be refreshed, so the system decides when to refresh and you will see - after you add the mouse listener - that your drawing will appear once you hide and show again the drawing window.

So you need to have JFrame as global - why dont you have you class extend JFrame and so no need to have some extra JFrame.